# Does PyPy work with asyncio?

Tags: python, performance, asynchronous, python-asyncio, pypy

Does PyPy support the aio and Python 3.5?

I need the performance of `PyPy` and asynchrous code of `asyncio`. Also I need to use `async/await` in my code. Is that possible?

If so, what are the nuances?

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe worth noting: [Trio](https://github.com/python-trio/trio) is a friendly asyncio alternative. There are [a number of differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482969/what-is-the-core-difference-between-asyncio-and-trio/49485603#49485603). Relevant here though: Trio fully supports pypy (e.g., every change is tested on pypy).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The current version of PyPy (version 7.2.0 at the time of writing) supports asyncio on at least Linux and Windows.

---

Old, now outdated (as of 2019-10-20) notes:

Currently there is a PyPy version (v7.0) compatible with Python 3.5 and a beta version (v7.1.1) compatible with Python 3.6.  Both versions support asyncio on Linux (and probably macOS, but I didn’t try myself), but only the latter supports asyncio on Windows.

---

Old, now outdated (as of 2019-04-16) notes:

Currently PyPy supports Python 3.5, so asyncio should just work.  However Python 3.x on Windows is still beta-quality.  Unfortunately currently the extension module for overlapped IO, which is needed to run asyncio on Windows, isn't yet implemented.

---

Old, now outdated (as of 2018-06-10) notes:

Currently PyPy supports Python 3.5.  Note that PyPy's Python 3 support is only beta quality in the moment.  We are continuously working on improving it.  It's not yet production-ready, though.  Most code involving `asyncio` should just work.  If not, please [check the open bug reports](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues?status=new&status=open) or [create a new one](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/new) or let me know here in the comments.

---

Old, now outdated (as of 2017-08-18) notes:

Currently PyPy supports Python 3.3.  This means that you can [install asyncio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asyncio) on PyPy3.3.  Note that PyPy's 3.3 support is only alpha / beta quality in the moment.  We are however actively working on increasing performance and compatibility with CPython.

The `async` / `await` feature was added in Python 3.5.  We started a very experimental branch with Python 3.5 support, but it's still got a long way to go.  Luckily we have a GSoC student working on it currently, but still it could take several years (depending on how much donations and volunteer work we receive).

EDIT 1: Previously there was a feature missing to run asyncio.  It was implemented shortly before this edit.  The answer was edited accordingly.

EDIT 2: We just released an alpha version of PyPy3.3.  We don't recommend anyone to try the old PyPy3 release supporting only Python 3.2.  This is why I rewrote most of the answer.

---

Old, now obsolete (as of 2016-05-30) notes:

The PyPy3 version from the website is very old and only implements Python 3.2 - we haven't done a release for over one and a half year.  Because Python 3.2 is missing the `yield from` feature, asyncio won't work with this version.

Comment: Apparently there's PyPy3.5 now?

Comment: Well, PyPy3.5 is still not complete or production-ready. But in the last year our focus was mostly only on PyPy3.5, so I should update my answer.

Comment: PyPy3.5 [doesn't seem to support](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2757/cant-import-asyncio-on-windows-importerror) asyncio until the native part of the module is reimplemented in Python.

Comment: @user PyPy3's Windows support (in general, not just for asyncio) is still in beta. I'll make it more clear in the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

No. According to [PyPy website](http://pypy.org/) it is only Python 3.2.5 compliant, while asyncio requires Python 3.4 (actually can be installed using pip on 3.3, thanks @dirn). Also on [Asyncio Wiki](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/Benchmarks), it is stated that asyncio doesn't work on PyPy yet (though Wiki was last updated in August 2015).

Comment: asyncio was added to the stdlib in 3.4, and can be installed through pip on 3.3. That doesn't affect the answer about PyPy, though.

Comment: this guy says otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960747/stackless-in-pypy-and-pypy-greenlet-differences

Comment: maybe you should just try installing with pip asyncio

Comment: This answer is now incorrect due to the latest release of pypy3 5.5.0 Please consider editing the answer, or deleting.